# Not able to scroll fixed Div

Tags: html, css

Its working fine for large screen size , but if screen height is not enough big as fixed DIV height, than I am not able to see overflowed part. It would be great if I could able to scroll this to see the bottom part of fixed DIV. 
I have added some garbage data in fixed DIV.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .html{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    #body{
        background-color: red;
        height: 1500px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #tem{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    width:200px;
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body id="body">
    Body
    <div id="tem">

    Fixed Div
    java - Is it possible, In JSP, to print the value of a variable ...
    stackoverflow.com/.../is-it-possible-in-jsp-to-print-the-value-of-a-variabl...
    Aug 21, 2009 - This will achieve the same effect as @Chii's answer: <c:set var="attributeName" value="foo"/> <% out.println(pageContext .getAttribute (attributeName) ...
    Simple JSP output : Basics « JSP « Java - Java2s
    www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/SimpleJSPoutput.htm
    Simple JSP output : Basics « JSP « Java. ... <BR> <jsp:setProperty name="bean1" property="message" value="No Problem. ... 17. pwd -- print working directory.
    Scriptlets - JSP Tutorial
    www.jsptut.com/scriptlets.jsp
    JSP also allows you to write blocks of Java code inside the JSP. You do this by placing ... we are generating the HTML directly by printing to the "out" variable.
    How to view System.out.print(hai); in jsp page - CodeRanch
    www.coderanch.com/t/293160/JSP/java/view-System-print-hai-jsp
    I am getting the output as "Hello World!". why i am not getting the output of System.out.print(); while if i my code is like "<%=AcNo%>" i a.
    how to print values on jsp page fetched from servlet (JSP ...
    www.coderanch.com/t/571948/JSP/java/print-values-jsp-page-fetched
    how can i bring these variables from servlet page to jsp page
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try overflow: auto or overflow:scroll in your div

Comment: @dr_debug overflow:scroll works if I enter more data than the fixed DIV height and screen in larger than fixed DIV height. But it is not working if screen height is less than the fixed DIV height.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/0y4reomh/

Comment: not exactly, I want to display a fixed div on screen on button click. But the data of whole fixed DIV is not visible if screen is small.